# Using cin.get() doesn't seem to read the character I'm expecting. What's wrong?

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, cin

so I'm working on this program to perform a menu of basic tasks, one of which is to tell whether a character input by the user is uppercase, lowercase, or not a letter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int mi;

    cout << "1) Area of Circle" << endl;
    cout << "2) Character Detection" << endl;
    cout << "3) Capitalization 1-3-5" << endl;
    cout << "4) Binomial Roots" << endl;
    cout << "0) Quit" << endl;

    cin >> mi;

    switch (mi) {
        case 2:
        {
            char c;
            cout << "input a character:  ";
            cin.get(c);
            cin.ignore(); /////// unsure if using this properly
            if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {cout << "c is lower case" << endl;}
            else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {cout << "C IS UPPER CASE" << endl;}
            else { cout << "C is not a letter" << endl;}
        }
            break;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

after selecting 2 and inputting a *letter* (or any other character) the output is always "C is not a letter."
What confuses me is that if I take what's in case 2 and put it in a separate program, i.e.

```
using namespace std;
int main () {
    char c;
    cout << "input a character:  ";
    cin.get(c);
    if ('a' <= c && 'z' >= c) {cout << "c is lower case" << endl;}
    else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'z') {cout << "C IS UPPER CASE" << endl;}
    else { cout << "C is not a letter" << endl;}
    return 0;
}
```

It works exactly how it's supposed to, and I don't even need cin.ignore(), because for some reason it only skips the user input part when it's in the switch statement.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Could I suggest the use of `isupper()` and `islower()`?

Comment: hm I actually haven't learned those ones and I'm actually not allowed to include things we haven't learned in lecture (this is for a class assignment).  Do you see anything wrong with, say, the cin.get() part?  Or perhaps the curly brackets?

Comment: You could've solved this by printing out what `mi` and `c` were just before you tested them. For `c` you probably would've wanted to print out it's value as an integer. This would've given you some really good hints as to exactly what was going wrong.

Comment: I actually did test print out c and it came out as a blank space (sorry, should have included that) which led me to believe it was some issue with either cin.get(c) or cin.ignore().

Comment: @zeurosis - It wasn't a blank space, but it was something equally invisible. If you had done `int tmp = c; cout << tmp << endl;` you would've seen '10'. `'A'` is 65, and `'a'` is 97. But `'\n'` is 10.

Comment: Try that in a small program: `int tmp = 'A'; cout << tmp;`. You'll see 65. :-) The coding table that maps letters to numbers is called, well, there are a few of them. But for your purposes knowing ASCII should suffice for now, since you're a beginner.

Comment: If you want to really toast your noodle, do `int tmp = '2'; cout << tmp << endl;`. _grin_ The single quotes around the 2 are important. Don't worry too much about it for now, but it will become important later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `cin>>` instead of `cin.get()` as  the `cin.get()` after every initialization is there to "grab" the newline character that gets put in the stream every time you press enter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

int mi;

cout << "1) Area of Circle" << endl;
cout << "2) Character Detection" << endl;
cout << "3) Capitalization 1-3-5" << endl;
cout << "4) Binomial Roots" << endl;
cout << "0) Quit" << endl;

cin >> mi;

switch (mi) {
    case 2:
    {
        char c;
        cout << "input a character:  ";
        cin>>c;
        cin.ignore(); /////// unsure if using this properly
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {cout << "c is lower case" << endl;}
        else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') {cout << "C IS UPPER CASE" << endl;}
        else { cout << "C is not a letter" << endl;}
    }
        break;
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: that worked!  thanks!  say, do you know the reason why cin.get() acted differently in a switch statement than not in one?

Comment: There's no difference in a switch or not. The formatted input take the number, leaving the newline. The get takes the newline which is not upper or lowercase. Put an ignore after the formatted input and it should work too. https://ideone.com/4cSuKV

Comment: @zeurosis - It didn't. The switch statement has nothing to do with your problem. Your problem is that there was a newline (the enter key) sitting there in the buffer waiting to be read after the number was read. `cin.get` grabs the next character no matter what it is. `cin >> c;` will skip 'whitespace' characters, which include newlines (which is what your problem was) and spaces. If you had printed out the integer value of c before the `if` statement it would've shown up as `10`, the value for `'\n'` (aka the newline character).

Comment: @zeurosis - Let me guess, before you put in the `cin.ignore();` it would immediately come out with "C is not a letter" before you typed anything, right?

Comment: yes, when it was in the switch statement it would, however in a separate program (not using switch) I didn't even include a cin.ignore() after cin.get() and it worked exactly how I wanted it too.  I'm confused because you're saying that it doesn't make a difference, but as I essentially copy and pasted the same code in the separate program into the switch statement and it behaved differently, that made me think the difference was the switch statement.  Is there a reason I didn't need .ignore in the separate one but i did in the switch?

Comment: @zeurosis - RIght, but that program doesn't ask you to put in a number first, you just type the letter right away right? You type 'enter' after the number, right? The 'enter' is a character. When you weren't reading the number you got the letter you typed right away. When you read the number, the 'enter' character was still left to read, so that's what `cin.get(c)` read, not the letter that was right after it. It's not the 'switch' that made the difference, but the fact you put in `2<enter>A`. You read the `2` entered the switch, then read the `<enter>` which is not a letter.

Comment: @zeurosis - If you left the `switch` there, and replaced `cin >> mi;` with `mi = 2;` your program would go back to working fine.

Comment: note that `cin.ignore()` just ignores one character. The program will still have the original problem if the user types an extra space before pressing enter. To deal with this properly you should use arguments to `ignore` so that it ignores the entire remainder of the line.